# How to find updated date in processing instruction - XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I am try to create attribute `lastUpdatedOn` in `p` element if find the processing instruction in `p` element and create the value `updated date`.
**Input XML**

```
<root>
    <p content-type="new">Ongoing technological and <?lastUpdatedOn 20/01/2021?>privacy developments present practicing <?lastUpdatedOn 27/01/2021?>attorneys with significant challenges in the field of information privacy and <?lastUpdatedOn 25/01/2020?>security.</p>
    <p content-type="new">Developments present <?lastUpdatedOn 26/01/2021?>practicing.</p>
    <p content-type="new">Practicing the Labs.</p>
</root>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<root>
    <p content-type="new" lastupdatedon="27/01/2021">Ongoing technological and <?lastUpdatedOn 20/01/2021?>privacy developments present practicing <?lastUpdatedOn 27/01/2021?>attorneys with significant challenges in the field of information privacy and <?lastUpdatedOn 25/01/2020?>security.</p>
    <p content-type="new" lastupdatedon="26/01/2021">Developments present <?lastUpdatedOn 26/01/2021?>practicing.</p>
    <p content-type="new">Practicing the Labs.</p>
</root>
```

**XSLT Code**

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:if test="processing-instruction(lastUpdatedOn)">
            <xsl:attribute name="lastupdatedon">
                <xsl:value-of select="processing-instruction(lastUpdatedOn)"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right pattern or test is `processing-instruction('lastUpdatedOn')`. I would stuff it into the match of the `p` e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="p[processing-instruction('lastUpdatedOn')]">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, processing-instruction('lastUpdatedOn'), node() except processing-instruction('lastUpdatedOn')"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('lastUpdatedOn')">
   <xsl:attribute select="{name()}" select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

the rest can be handled by the identity transformation with e.g. `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>`.

As you seem to have multiple processing instruction sorting them with

```
<xsl:template match="p[processing-instruction('lastUpdatedOn')]">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, sort(processing-instruction('lastUpdatedOn'), (), function($p) { xs:date(replace($p, '([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})', '$3-$2-$1')) })[last()], node() except processing-instruction('lastUpdatedOn')"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('lastUpdatedOn')">
   <xsl:attribute name="lastupdatedon" select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

can help to just display the last date. Higher-order `fn:sort` is available in Saxon PE and EE since 9.8 at least and in Saxon HE for 10 and later.

The above would move the date to the attribute but delete the processing instructions from the `p`, if you need to retain them perhaps

```
  <xsl:template match="p[processing-instruction('lastUpdatedOn')]">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, sort(processing-instruction('lastUpdatedOn')!xs:date(replace(., '([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})', '$3-$2-$1')))[last()], node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match=".[. instance of xs:date]">
     <xsl:attribute name="lastupdatedon" select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
```

is a better approach.

Comment: Sir, Please check 1st `p` element not found lastupdated date attribute value `25/01/2020` s/b `27/01/2021`.

Comment: @Sam, due to a small screen I didn't notice a `p` can contain several of those processing instructions. So is there a need to extract the dates and sort them to only insert the latest date in the attribute value?

Comment: Yes Sir I want only insert the latest date in the attribute value.

Comment: Sir, Thank you so much it's perfectly work.

Comment: Sir, I am requesting you can you check my previous question? I have not solve the previous question.